# Get current process id in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

To get process_id in **Java**, we use `ProcessHandle.current().pid();`,. Jow we can get current-process-id in `Systemverilog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the builtin `process` class

```
begin
  process pid;
  pid = process::self();
  ...
end
```

See section *9.7 Fine-grain process control* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)

Answer (score 0):

SystemVerilog does not have any facility to get 'pid' of its process. It provides an object to do limited process control in a system-independent way.  You can check lrm 9.7 for available controls.

However, it is possible to get pid using DPI or PLI functions, using 'c' calls. But implementation could be system and simulator dependent.

For example, the following works with VCS on linux:

```
module pid();
   import "DPI-C" function int getpid();
   initial begin
      $display("%d", getpid());
   end
endmodule // pid
```

In the above `getpid()` is a standard *libc* function which is callable from the simulator. It also seems to work with vcs, mentor, and cadence in EDA playground, but fails with aldec.

Since the function is globally defined, there is no need to define a dpi function body at least for the three simulators. However, you might need to define a different dpi function with a 'c' body to make it more portable.

Comment: Process IDs on the host OS do not map to SystemVerilog process ids.

Comment: OP asked about `ProcessHandle.current().pid()` from java, which is a **native** process id.  This id is returned by *getpid()*.